# What is the point of String.Concat(String, String, String, String)

Tags: c#, string

If you have 5 or more strings you'd like to concatenate with `String.Concat()`, then it uses `Concat(String[])`.

Why not just use `Concat(String[])` all the time and do away with the need for `Concat(String, String)`, `Concat(String, String, String)` and `Concat(String, String, String, String)`.

What is Microsoft's reason for not just using `Concat(String[])` whenever you want to concatenate one or more strings?

Comment: (Was `params` in C#1 / .NET1.0?)

Comment: @user2864740 i was thinking the same, just checked and msdn says that string.concat overload with params was included in 1.0

Comment: @RobertLevy Going more tangential: can `params` be applied as a backwards-compatible change (e.g. reflected in forward API)? Were you able to dig up the original 1.0 docu.?

Comment: My opinion is that performance gain here is negligible. You can try and test it yourself. Mostly this is for convenience - akin to syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to reference source [`Concat(String[])`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib) implemented this way:

```
public static string Concat(params string[] values)
{       
    int totalLength = 0; // variable to calculate total length
    string[] strArray = new string[values.Length]; // second array
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) // first loop
    {
        string str = values[i];            
        totalLength += strArray[i].Length;           
    }

    return ConcatArray(strArray, totalLength);
}

private static string ConcatArray(string[] values, int totalLength)
{
    string dest = FastAllocateString(totalLength);
    int destPos = 0; // variable to calculate current position
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) // second loop
    {
        FillStringChecked(dest, destPos, values[i]);
        destPos += values[i].Length;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

`Concat(String, String, String)` and similar methods are more optimized. They avoid creation of string array for parameters, they avoid loops (each loop has variable, increment and check logic), they don't use variables for calculating total string length and current position in resulting string:

```
public static string Concat(string str0, string str1, string str2)
{
    int length = (str0.Length + str1.Length) + str2.Length;
    string dest = FastAllocateString(length);
    FillStringChecked(dest, 0, str0);
    FillStringChecked(dest, str0.Length, str1);
    FillStringChecked(dest, str0.Length + str1.Length, str2);
    return dest;
}
```

NOTE: I skipped parameter validation code (nulls are replaced with empty strings) to show only difference.

Comment: so why did Microsoft decide to stop at Concat(String, String, String, String), why not create Concat(String, String, String, String, String)? Where do you draw the line?

Comment: "They avoid creation of string array for parameters"... Wait, what? it's not the method that creates string array, it's its caller!

Comment: @zespri `Concat(params string[] values)` it's `params`

Comment: so there's no particular reason for the last method having 4 string parameters, they just randomly decided on 4?

Comment: With anything like that you have to have some sort of cut off. 4 seems logical, since you can chain them: `string.Concat("1", "2", "3", string.Concat("4", "5", 6", "7"))`... The same use case was given to `Tuple<T1, T2, T3..` .. etc, where `T8` is another `Tuple` if you need larger ones.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I don't think there is some specific reason. Probably they decided, that concatenating five strings does not happen pretty often

Comment: @SimonWhitehead there will be one additional string created in that case

Comment: I assume they looked at as much production code as they could and decided that offering up to 4 covered most of the code (especially after the compiler optimized calls) - Microsoft has done a lot of very pragmatic decisions in C# for common LOB apps. Note that for example `System.Action` only went up to T4 in .net 3.5, and then .net 4.0 added overloads up to T16 based on real world need. I guess there isn't much real world need for super efficient string.Concat past 4, presumably because people use StringBuilders anyway for that.

Comment: @MichaelStum it's actually worse to use a StringBuilder if you have 5 strings. Have a look at the "Five Strings" section here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

Comment: @Backwards_Dave Curious: Was the benchmark done with optimizations on (Release build) and after one dry run to about the JIT overhead? I know that StringBuilder can be slower at times (and usually is for 3 and 4). But yeah, it's not really an exact science there since GC pressure also comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is done for performance reasons. You can actually invoke Concat with 5 string parameters, but if you look at the generated code it runs the method that accepts the array. Adding strings simultaneously is faster than adding them serially. Check this link below for more info.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

Comment: Unfortunately that page does not show the `Concat(String[])` form so no direct comparison is made.

Comment: @user2864740 if you look at the IL dissambler note on the five strings, it states there is not five parameter overload and the params version is used, which is the <code>Concat(string[])</code> constructor.